# Deleting record from gridview in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the below gridview on a page to display users with a role of "Reviewer". The grid pulls up the records correctly. On the gridview is a "delete" button to remove the Reviewer role. The stored procedure that is called is working correctly when ran manually, but I seem to be missing something on the aspx or codebehind page as while no error is returned, no record is deleted either.

aspx control for gridview:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Caption="Current Reviewers" AllowSorting="True" PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
CaptionAlign="Top" EmptyDataText="No Reviewers Configured." PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true" PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" PagerStyle-Font-Size="Large"
AutoGenerateColumns="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#cccccc" DataKeyNames="UserId" OnRowDeleting="DeleteRecord">
<Columns>

     <asp:BoundField DataField="UserId" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="300" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="250" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete the record?')">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkB" runat="Server" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserId") %>' CommandName="DeleteRecord"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </span>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Updated with full code behind:

```
namespace cs1.Admin
{
public partial class ReviewerMaintenance : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindDropDownList1();
        }
    }
    private void BindDropDownList1()
    {

        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        string selectSQL = String.Format("SELECT Id as UserId, FirstName + ' ' + LastName As Name from AspNetUsers where Id in(SELECT  UserId from AspNetUserRoles where RoleId = 1)");
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(ds, "Reviewer");

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindDropDownList1(); //bindgridview will get the data source and bind it again
    }

    protected void DeleteRecord(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        string UserId = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());
        SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand();
        {
            conn.Open();
            dCmd.CommandText = "Reviewer_Delete";
            dCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            dCmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UserId;
            dCmd.Connection = conn;
            dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            // Refresh the data

            BindDropDownList1();
            dCmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();

        }

    }


}
}
```

Comment: if you put a breakpoint in your `DeleteRecord` method, does it get hit? I'm not sure the syntax you're using for binding to the method is correct.

Comment: Could we see the stored procedure that you create?

Comment: @TZHX - I tried putting in breakpoints, and code does stop and wait to be told to continue as expected, so looks like everything is being called.

Comment: Fyi, use the `using`-statement instead, on that way you'll ensure that the connection gets closed even in case of an error.

Comment: You have commented `// Refresh the data` but your code doesn't refresh the grid

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I have verified that the record is not being deleted, so it is not a refresh issue, and page load on postback should be dealing with rebinding/displaying the gridview (code not shown).

Comment: @BrentOliver: what means "postback should be dealing with rebinding grid"? The opposite should be true, you should not databind the grid on postbacks from `Page_Load`. Otherwise the `OnRowDeleting` event would not be called.

Comment: @BrentOliver please answer TZHX's comment. I have never attached to a command like you're doing; I've always done it through the [OnRowCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: @NicholasV. - Think I have added a breakpoint into the code behind for the DeleteRecord section,,, and it does not appear to be called. I'm new at ASP.NET programming, so I can't figure out why this is not working. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: @BrentOliver Please see my answer in a moment.

Comment: @NicholasV. - Not sure why, but your solution throws an error. It is not able to apply the RowIndex to the string UserId

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `OnRowCommand` event of the GridView to handle this.

**In your Gridview markup**:

ensure `OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"` is present.

**In your code behind**:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    { /* Set a breakpoint here and make sure: 
           A.) You are hitting this method 
           B.) Get value of e.CommandName */
        if (e.CommandName == "EditRecord")
        {
            // Run your edit/update logic here if needed
        }
        if (e.CommandName == "DeleteRecord")
        {
            // Delete the record here
            string UserId = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());
            SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand();
            {
                conn.Open();
                dCmd.CommandText = "Reviewer_Delete";
                dCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                dCmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UserId;
                dCmd.Connection = conn;
                dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                // Refresh the data

                BindDropDownList1();
                dCmd.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: = Adding the above results in an error: 'admin_reviewermaintenance_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GridView1_RowCommand' and no extension method 'GridView1_RowCommand' accepting a first argument of type 'admin_reviewermaintenance_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a very simple thing. On the aspx page I had both the OnRowDeleting and CommandName elements set to the same value of "DeleteRecord".

Changing the CommandName value to "Delete" allowed the code to be evaluated and the stored procedure to be called successfully.